# Pulling the title of a wall post

Tags: api, facebook-graph-api

just wondering if there is a way, using the API, to pull out the post title and desc separately? Essentially I would like this:

```
$post['author'] = $p['from'];    
$post['title'] = $p['?'];    
$post['content'] = $p['?'];
```

thanks

edit. I would also be happy with pulling just the title of a new post...

edit2. my mistake, there is no title in facebook posts. my coffee finally kicked in and my ignorance was revealed to me.

Answer (score 0):

Try this http://www.wescutshall.com/2011/12/getting-facebook-user-data-with-php/

As you can see, you need some special permission from FB to get the data you need.
After that you can use their api, as described in the url before, to get your data.

EDIT:
Here you can see wich info you can get of a person:
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/login/extended-profile-properties/

And here, wich you can get of a message (user_status):
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/location_post/

after you have this you can pull out the information using:

```
$config = array(
‘appId’ => FBAPPID,
‘secret’ => FBAPPSECRET,
);

$facebook = new Facebook($config);
$fbuserid = $facebook->getUser();

$params = array(
“scope” => “user_status”,
“redirect_uri” => “http://www.yoursite.com/”
);

$loginurl = $facebook->getLoginUrl($params);
```

Comment: Yes, and I am using their graph API to pull the data. I just can't seem to find a separate call for the title & msg body...